# Creating graph from PNG map

Tags: java, algorithm, image-processing

I have a map, on which there are passages painted with one specific color, and people can walk only on this passages - so any other color is an obstacle. Is there any tool/library/algorithm, that would allow to create graph from such kind of map?

Comment: When you create a game like this, you should use the [model / view / controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  The model would contain the information to create your map and create your graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any need for a library or tool to build this. The task at hand is simple enough and unique enough to justify a new implementation.

Below I outline the components I would build to accomplish this task, specifically highlighting their narrow responsibilities.

**Graph [T]**

The graph represents a binary relationship between node-pairs in a collection of nodes. `T` represents the payload associated with those nodes -- in your use case, the pixel coordinates of the image. We make no assumptions about whether the graph is directed or acyclic or anything like that.

**Node [T]**

A single node in the graph. It has a generic payload of type `T` and a method called `GetNeighboringNodes`.

**PassageGraphBuilder**

This class is responsible for creating a `Graph<PixelCoordinates>` out of an `Image`. It contains configuration for which `Color` represents a passage within the given `Image`, and for which directionality (just up/down/left/right or the diagonals as well?) allows connectedness.

It performs this task by creating a `Node<PixelCoordinates>` for each pixel in the `Image`. It then creates relationships between those nodes by inspecting the color of every neighboring pixel in the `Image`.

**WorldToGraphMap**

This component has the responsibility of mapping world coordinates to pixel coordinates. This allows the scale of your world to be independent of the data used to drive it. It has methods like `GetWorldCoordinatesForNodeCenter(Node<PixelCoordinates>)` and `GetNodeForWorldCoordinates(WorldCoordinates)`.

**Then you can...**

Finally, you can do the following:

- Take as input a new desired position (in world coordinates) for the player, presumably driven by controller input,
- Call `GetNodeForWorldCoordinates(WorldCoordinates)` to determine the node in the graph that the new position corresponds to,
- Check the player's current node to determine if the two nodes are neighbors:
- If the new node is a neighbor of the old one, allow the movement;
- Otherwise, disallow it.

Of course there are many more intricacies to constructing a real navmesh, but this should get you going for this use case.